# Spring Cloud Config Server - Constant Polling

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-config

I have deployed an instance of spring cloud config server in pivotal cloud foundry env. There are 3 instances of this app running. I tailed the logs and can see it constantly polling the github server.

> [RTR/11] OUT ctpconfigserver.app.cloud.net -
>   [2017-08-14T16:02:36.740+0000] "GET /application/sp-prd,cloud/master
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 0 93 "-" "Java/1.8.0_101" "" ""
>   x_forwarded_for:"" x_forwarded_proto:"https"
>   vcap_request_id:"f48aaa7a-1210-4fee-4471-9be18113c7b5"
>   response_time:1.754105382
>   app_id:"74b03aee-f6be-4ea5-9063-d1db83d61f70" app_index:"1"
>   x_b3_traceid:"8a4bf40fb7d4675e" x_b3_spanid:"8a4bf40fb7d4675e"
>   x_b3_parentspanid:"-"

Is there a way to determine what is causing config server to constantly poll github and stop it from polling frequently?

Comment: The config client doesn't do polling. It's likely that something is hitting the local health endpoint which in turn hitting config server

Comment: Thanks spencergibb , is there a way for me to confirm if local health endpoint is being hit?

Comment: On pcf I think the platform does to monitor if it is up

Comment: If something is hitting the health end point, you would see references to that in the logs.  Every request to the application that goes through the GoRouter will generate an access log entry with the tag `[RTR/xx]`.  The only way this wouldn't happen is if you were using Container to Container networking & whatever was hitting the health end point did so over C2C networking (this would bypass GoRouter).

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I'll check this

Comment: You can see the health check type being used by the platform by running `cf curl /v2/apps/$(cf app --guid <app-name>) | grep 'health_check'`.  The output will show the type which could be process, port or http.  If it's http, it will show the end point being used to do the health check.  If it's port, it's just doing a TCP port check and not actually hitting any end point.

Comment: Awesome! Will check and update